# HTML5 audio - currentTime attribute inaccurate?

Tags: javascript, html, audio, mp3, html5-audio

I'm playing around a bit with the HTML5 `<audio>` tag and I noticed some strange behaviour that has to do with the `currentTime` attribute.

I wanted to have a local audio file played and let the `timeupdate` event detect when it finishes by comparing the `currentTime` attribute to the `duration` attribute.

This actually works pretty fine if I let the song play from the beginning to the end - the end of the song is determined correctly.

However, changing the `currentTime` manually (either directly through JavaScript or by using the browser-based audio controls) results in the API not giving back the correct value of the `currentTime` anymore but seems to set it some seconds ahead of the position that's actually playing.

(These "some seconds" ahead are based on Chrome, Firefox seems to completely going crazy which results in the discrepancy being way bigger.)

A little jsFiddle example about the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/yp3o8cyw/2/

Can anybody tell me why this happens - or did I just not getting right what the API should do?

P.S.: I just noticed this actually only happens with MP3-encoded files, OGG files are totally doing fine.

Comment: I'm running smack up to this exact issue. I have only had a problem with "long" mp3s, the longer, the more unreliable the currentTime property becomes when skipping forward and backwards. This is a real problem for me. Have you ever been able to solve it with mp3s?

Comment: As mentioned in a comment below the accepted answer: You can use alternative JavaScript techniques that do the decoding of the MP3 file instead of relying on HTML5 audio. Aurora.js did a great job for me. (https://github.com/audiocogs/aurora.js/)

Comment: Thanks Loilo, I'll check out aurora.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First off, I'm not actually able to reproduce your problem on my machine, but I only have a short MP3 file handy at the moment, so that might be the issue.  In any case, I think I can explain what's going on.

MP3 files (MPEG) are very simple streams and do not have absolute positional data within them.  It isn't possible from reading the first part of the file to know at what byte offset some arbitrary frame begins.  The media player seeks in the file by needle dropping.  That is, it knows the size of the entire track and roughly how far into the track your time offset is.  It guesses and begins decoding, picking up as soon as it synchronizes to the next frame header.  This is an imprecise process.

Ogg is a more robust container and has time offsets built into its frame headers.  Seeking in an Ogg file is much more straightforward.

The other issue is that most browsers that support MP3 do so only because the codec is already available on your system.  Playing Ogg Vorbis and MP3 are usually completely different libraries with different APIs.  While the web standards do a lot to provide a common abstraction, minor implementation details cause quirks like you are seeing.

Comment: Sadly this sounds pretty plausible, though I wonder that the browser can't handle it even if it's fully loaded - but I'm actually not very familiar with how the MP3 format itself works.
So how do other HTML5/JS frameworks solve this? Do you think diving deeper into this topic (read about an AudioContext API) can solve this?

Comment: @Loilo Fully downloaded and fully decoded are a two different things.  Even if the browser has all of the data stream available, it probably isn't going to decode all the way through just to get a sample accurate seek point.  Old MP3 players did this (Winamp v1) and it was painful!  Although these days, decoding MP3 happens much faster than realtime.  You can read more about the bitstream format here:  http://mpgedit.org/mpgedit/mpeg_format/mpeghdr.htm  More information on the actual codec itself here:  http://www.mp3-converter.com/mp3codec/

Comment: Thanks for the links.
I just tested more such stuff and I could even reproduce the problem with popular JS libraries like SoundJS and others - so it really seems be solely based on the MP3 format. What a shame. So I probably can't code a web based audio player for my MP3s. ;)

Comment: @Loilo All of those libraries are using the exact same browser implementation in the background.  The only one that doesn't is Aurora.

Comment: Yep, sadly there doesn't seem to be any way around. So I can just hope that OGG will get a little more popular. ;)
Thanks for your help though!

Comment: Oh, and +1 for mentioning Aurora.js. This thing looks really awesome!

Answer (score 16):

After hours of battling this mysterious issue, I believe I have figured out what is going on here. This is not a question of .ogg vs .mp3, this is a question of variable vs. constant bitrate encoding on mp3s (and perhaps other file types).

I cannot take the credit for discovering this, only for scouring the interwebs. Terrill Thompson, a gentlemen and scholar, wrote a [detailed article](http://terrillthompson.com/blog/624) about this problem back on February 1st, 2015, which includes the following excerpt:

> *Variable Bit Rate (VBR) uses an algorithm to efficiently compress the
> media, varying between low and high bitrates depending on the
> complexity of the data at a given moment. Constant Bit Rate (CBR), in
> contrast, compresses the file using the same bit rate throughout. VBR
> is more efficient than CBR, and can therefore deliver content of
> comparable quality in a smaller file size, which sounds attractive,
> yes?*
>
> *Unfortunately, there’s a tradeoff if the media is being streamed
> (including progressive download), especially if timed text is
> involved. As I’ve learned, VBR-encoded MP3 files do not play back with
> dependable timing if the user scrubs ahead or back.*

I'm writing this for anyone else who runs into this syncing problem (which makes precise syncing of audio and text impossible), because if you do, it's a real nightmare to figure out what is going on.

My next step is to do some more testing, and finally to figure out an efficient way to convert all my .mp3s to constant bit rate. I'm thinking FFMPEG may be able to help, but I'll explore that in another thread. Thanks also to Loilo for originally posting about this issue and Brad for the information he shared.

Comment: Please let me know if you had any luck with this!

Comment: Hey @AlexKempton, after messing with this for a while I found that it actually IS absolutely related to variable vs. constant/fixed bitrates on your mp3s. Long story short, use constant/fixed bitrates and you shouldn't have a problem (from my experience). Use variable bit rates, and you could run into nasty timing issues. http://terrillthompson.com/blog/624

Comment: Wow - thank you for putting this out there. Not an easy thing to search for. Simply converting my .wav files to .mp3 (or almost anything) on the server solves this problem.