# How to convert MP3's to constant bitrate using FFMPEG

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, mp3, html5-audio, web-audio-api

I have found that MP3's encoded with variable bit rate cause the currentTime property to be [reported incorrectly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25468063/html5-audio-currenttime-attribute-inaccurate?noredirect=1#comment62766676_25468063), especially when scrubbing. That has wreaked havok on my app and has been a nightmare to debug.

I believe I need to convert all my MP3's to constant bitrate. Can FFMPEG (or something else) help me do that efficiently?

- Props to Terrill Thompson for attempting to [pin this down](http://terrillthompson.com/blog/624)*

Comment: Possibly an *XY problem*. I'm not convinced this is a good solution. The link mentions that it only used encoders that use FFmpeg, which in turn uses libmp3lame. No other encoders were tested. Did you try an output directly from LAME? Did you try a non-LAME based MP3 encoder?

Comment: I did not. Though the post that covers my original problem is here (no real solution): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25468063/html5-audio-currenttime-attribute-inaccurate?noredirect=1#comment62766676_25468063 ... Those guys were incorrect (imo) in thinking that it was as simple as using the .ogg format (didn't work). Also, in my application I source mp3's from all over the world, so it isn't feasible to manually encode them all. I will need to bulk encode them quickly and ensure they have a fixed bitrate so that the html5 audio currentTime property reports accurately.

Comment: And for what it's worth LordNeckbeard, I am happy to be wrong on this if that's the case. Anything at this point to address the issue, seriously. If anyone can help me get to the bottom of this he will have a tremendous neckbeard so I think we're on to something... To answer your question I'm not sure how to know what other encoder to use and/or whether or not it uses LAME. Do you know of one off the top of your head I should test with to try and pin this down?

Comment: Do you have a sample input file I can encode to MP3? I have a few ideas to try, but just guesses really.

Comment: Does muxing the MP3 into a MP4 container help?

Comment: @BrianFitzGerald You realize raw MP3 doesn't have a timestamp, right?  It actually isn't possible to reliably scrub into an MP3 file.  You need a container for this.  And, I really recommend you don't re-encode your files... you're losing quality every time you do this.

Answer (score 1):

I also had issues with HTML5 being inaccurate for large mp3s. Since quality was not a big issue for my audio, I converted to  constant bit rate of 8kbps, sample rate 8k, mono and it solved my issues.

You can convert to a contant bit rate for a few files using [Audacity](https://www.audacityteam.org/) (export > save to mp3 > constant bit rate).

Or, using [FFMPEG](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/MP3):

```
ffmpeg -i input.wav -codec:a libmp3lame -b:a 8k output.mp3
```

If you also want to reduce to mono and a 8k sample rate:

```
ffmpeg -i input.wav -codec:a libmp3lame -b:a 8k -ac 1 -ar 8000 output.mp3
```

Using the second compressed an hour of audio to under 5MB.

Answer (score -1):

Something else is going on.  `currentTime` should not be influenced by the fact that you are using variable-bit rate MP3s.

Perhaps the context sampleRate is not the same as the sample rate as the MP3s?  That will mess up timing of the audio samples because WebAudio will resample the MP3s to the context sample rate.

Comment: Thanks for responding, Raymond. We are talking about an issue which only occurs in long mp3 files, and I have been able to reproduce with multiple files from different sources. This guy wrote something about it last year: http://terrillthompson.com/blog/624

Comment: Oh, I just remembered.  If you're using chrome, there is an issue with how chrome decodes an mp3 with webaudio.  It uses an estimate of the duration, and if the estimate is short, the file is truncated.  This is unfortunate, to say the least.

Comment: What would you do Raymond if you absolutely HAD to have accurate timing in your audio playback? For example to accurately sync textual captions with the words in the audio file. Thanks for any insight you can share.

Comment: Not sure what to do.  If you used webaudio you could load the entire file into memory. (I was assuming you were already doing this, but based on the test page, that's probably not true.)  Then there wouldn't be issues with bad sync.  But you'd have to fit it all into memory.

Comment: I have actually tried with web audio and there are still sync issues. For example, howlerjs (https://github.com/goldfire/howler.js/tree/2.0) uses web audio under the hood, and there is a flag (html5: true) to turn on html5 audio instead, which is intended to be used for long files. I have tried loading long files with the flag on and off (html5 vs. web audio) and in both cases have found syncing problems. I will do some more testing, but this guy seems to think wav files are reported more accurately. https://forestmist.org/blog/web-audio-api-loops-and-formats ... I guess I'll try that next.

Comment: If you can afford to use wav files, that would be the best.  If that doesn't work, you should complain loudly; the encoding for (basic) wav files is really simple so it would be hard to mess that up.

Comment: I don't know that I will be able to "afford" it in the end, Raymond, but at this point I just need to find something that actually works dependably in this regard as a starting point. Thanks a lot for your insight. I'm going to do some thorough testing and see what I come up with.

Comment: This answer is actually incorrect.  It isn't possible to get the timing exactly right.  The browser takes the length as returned in the response headers, and the bit rate, and guesstimates where to needle-drop in the stream, usually making a ranged request for that segment of the resource on the server.  With VBR, that guesstimate is going to be more wrong than it usually is.

Comment: What is wrong?  Perhaps I was too brief, but I was talking about `currentTime` for WebAudio's `AudioContext` `currentTime`, and that is independent of the MP3 encoding.