# can't set current time to a Audio element, in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, html5-audio, current-time

```js
aud = document.getElementById('audio element');
btn = document.getElementById('btn element');

btn.addEventListener("click", playpause, false);

aud.oncanplay = reSync(1200);

function playpause() {
 if (aud.paused) {
  aud.play();
 } else {
  aud.pause();
 }
}

function reSync(time) {
  aud.currentTime = time;
  console.log(aud.currentTime);
}
```

I have a audio file I would like to play on my website. But for some reason when I try to change the current time to as an example to 1200 it become 900 and something instead. The different does seem dependent on how big a change I'm trying to do. I have no idea on how to fix this.

Comment: could you link the specific audio file and the code you use to change the time?

Comment: is the audio really 20 minutes long? I wonder if the stream hasn't loaded enough to skip to that time

Comment: this is the relevant parts of my code, and sorry but I don't own the audio but the file is a 35 MB aac file.

Comment: you could use the `buffered` property to see if you are trying to seek outside of the available time range - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/buffered - or the `seekable` property is probably more appropriate https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/seekable

Comment: Refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12029509/html-5-audio-play-file-at-certain-time-point), specifically `your script will first need to be after the audio tag.` as we cannot see your `HTML`

Comment: @EGC - in the question, it seems the seek does occur, just not to the point in time reuired

Comment: yes Bravo the audio is 26 minutes long.

Comment: There appears to be a bug: [HTML5 audio - currentTime attribute inaccurate?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25468932/11700321)

Comment: the, as I suggested check the `buffered` and `seekable` properties

Comment: @EGC - no such problem 5 years later :D

Comment: Neat, okay, any chance it's [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42977670/11700321) ? `I had the same problem, and the reason was missing headers on the mp3 file, like: 'Content-Length, Content-Range, Content-Type'`

Comment: converting the file from a acc to ogg worked, thanks alot for the help u guys